# Execute blur before a jQuery click event

Tags: jquery

```
 $('[datakey=PhoneMobile').blur(function() {
        UniquePhoneService.ValidateUniquePhoneNumber($('[datakey=PhoneMobile]').val(), $('[datakey=accounttype]').val(), $('#FocusAccountCountry').val(), $('[datakey=enrollingaccountcode]').val(), function(result) {
            var $element = $('[datakey=PhoneMobile]').siblings('span.unique-phone-error');
            if (!result) {
                $element.text('<%= GetResourceValue("CustomerInfo", "DuplicatePhoneNumber", "Text")%>');
                Page_IsValid = false;
            } else {
                $element.text('');
                Page_IsValid === true ? Page_IsValid = true : Page_IsValid = false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have a form and it has a text box with a `blur()` this call a web service to validate some data, but when I click the `OK`
button the click is first executed then the blur, I want to execute the blur first, how can I do this?

Comment: you have one `});` too many, please check my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could submit the form AFTER you know your service validates your data, something like:

```
$('#ok').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

 $('[datakey=PhoneMobile').blur(function() {
        UniquePhoneService.ValidateUniquePhoneNumber($('[datakey=PhoneMobile]').val(), $('[datakey=accounttype]').val(), $('#FocusAccountCountry').val(), $('[datakey=enrollingaccountcode]').val(), function(result) {
            var $element = $('[datakey=PhoneMobile]').siblings('span.unique-phone-error');
            var Page_IsValid = true;
            if (!result) {
                $element.text('<%= GetResourceValue("CustomerInfo", "DuplicatePhoneNumber", "Text")%>');
                Page_IsValid = false;
            } else {
                $element.text('');
                Page_IsValid === true ? Page_IsValid = true : Page_IsValid = false;
            }
            if(Page_IsValid)
                $('#form').submit();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, to override the click event, and run it later

```
$("#myTextBox").click(function(event)(){
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){ clicked(params) }, 500);//Run function after 500 ms
});

function clicked(params){
    //Run on click
}
```